# Django form shows No File Chosen

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

My question is, why does the form show No File Chosen against the file fields even when a file is loaded (and how do I correct this)?

I have the following form (the relevant bits being the FileInput widgets):

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ['id',]
        widgets = {
            'user' : forms.HiddenInput(),
            'first_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'last_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'majors' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'university' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'grad_year' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control',
                                                 'type' : 'number'}),
            'resume' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'transcript' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'git_link' : forms.URLInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'linkedin_link' : forms.URLInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
        }
```

My view to save/display for is :

```
student = Student.objects.get(user=request.user)
form = StudentForm(instance=student)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=student)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Profile successfully updated.')
variables['form'] = form
return render (request, 'app/profile.html', variables)
```

And I am rendering it through HTML like this:

```
<form method='post' action="{% url 'add-profile' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-confirm="Please confirm you want to save the current data.  This will overright all previous data.">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table">
        {{form.as_table}}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

My question is, why does the form show No File Chosen against the file fields even when a file is loaded (and how do I correct this)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (which I don't like) has been to use `{{form.field}}` and for the URL fields include `{{form.field.url}}`.  I can then apply CSS formatting to remove the standard button and apply my own without the No File Chosen text.

Horrid